# Using an array as input in a recursive method in C

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

I am having a problem with using an array as input within a recursive function here is the problem: i set the array values to what i want in the first level of recursion , but the changes that are made to an array in level 2-3 of the recursion somehow change the array of the level 1 of recursion. This should not happen right? because everytime the method is recalled it should store the particular array for what it has been called right?

here is the code of the recursive method the method is called vertexCover:

```
 int vertexCover (int start, int covering, int seen [1000]){
        if(covering==0){

            if(start>numberOfEdges-1){
                return 1;
            }

            else{
                while(start<=numberOfEdges-1){
                    if(seen[edge1[start]]==0 && seen[edge2[start]]==0){
                        return 0;
                    }

                    start++;
                }

                return 1;
            }   

        }

        else{
            while(seen[edge1[start]]!=0 || seen[edge2[start]] !=0){
                start++;
                if(start>numberOfEdges-1){
                    return 1;
                }
            }

            seen[edge1[start]]=1;

            int a= vertexCover(start + 1, covering-1, seen);

            seen[edge1[start]]=0;
            seen[edge2[start]]=1;

            int b = vertexCover(start+1,covering-1,seen);

            if(a==1 || b==1){
                return 1;
            }

            else {
                return 0;   
            }
        }

    }
```

What I want to do is to make sure each call to the recursive method has its own unique array, changes made to the array not affecting the array stored from the previous call. For some reason it is not doing this.

Comment: Not unless you explicitly copy the array at each call, no.

Comment: All arguments passed to a function are call by value ( a copy is created ) , except for arrays, arrays are call by reference ( the array location is passed but it is not copied ). You need to create, inside the function, a copy of the array.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to do it you will need to copy you array like that.

```
int vertexCover (int start, int covering, const int array [1000]){
        int seen[1000];
        memcpy(seen, array, sizeof(seen));
...
}
```

but your program will be very slow if you do that so I think you should use short array or find another way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your function:

```
int vertexCover(int start, int covering, int seen [1000]) { ... }
```

Is treated identically to:

```
int vertexCover(int start, int covering, int *seen) { ... }
```

So changes made to `seen[0]` will be visible to all users of that pointer. If you want a local copy of the array, you'll need to explicitly make a copy of it.